# Python: iNotify_Simple getting files from other directories

Tags: python, inotify

I'm using inotify_simple to get notifications from a directory of directories. I'm accessing a directory that has multiple sub-directories, looping through those sub-directories and wanting to use inotify within each directory. My goal for this program is to be notified anytime anything happens (in particular, a creation of a file) in one of the sub-directories.

My file structure:

```
-mainDir
  -subDir1
    -file1
    -file2
  -subDir2
    -file3
    -file4
 ...etc.
```

I'm looping through the directories in mainDir, and setting that path as the path for inotify to search in:

```
 for directory in os.listdir(self.path):
   new_path = os.path.join(self.path, directory)
   new_curr =  self.inotify.new_curr_file_notification(new_path)
```

New path values are exactly what I expect:

```
 .../mainDir/subDir1
 .../mainDir/subDir2
```

When passing in new_path into my function (which is the path to give inotify), I'm expecting inotify to only look in that directory. However, I'm getting notifications that files in other directories are causing the notification.

```
path for inotify .../mainDir/subDir1
Event(wd=1, mask=256, cookie=0, name='someFileInSubDir2')
flags.CREATE
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? And, if anyone has any suggestions to make this process easier/better, I'm all ears! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of `inotify_simple`, and since it doesn't have a method called `new_curr_file_notification`, I'm guessing that's that's something you wrote. Without seeing that method, or some more code that demonstrates how you're using the library exactly, I unfortunately can't give you any advice, as there's not enough information to see how you're using `inotify_simple`.

If you post a complete example, I will probably be able to tell what's going wrong.

Feel free to post a bug report on the project't github if it looks like there might be a bug.